# Concatenating Zero to every row that has len() == 1.0 using loc[] methd

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, pandas-loc

I have a set of data with one column:

```
  New_Value
0   51
1   45
2    1
3   78
4    0
5   78
```

csv files do not represent the zero found after a digit. `10` becomes `1` and this presents inaccuracy in what I'm trying to do. I want to add a zero to every row that has one digit and leave those that has two digits as they are. I have tried the following code but still get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`.

```py
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('Hellow world')

    for index in df.index:
        if df.loc[index,'New_Value'].str.len()== 1.0:
           df['New_Value']= data['New_Value'].str.cat(0)
           
         else if df.loc[index,'New_Value'].str.len()== 2.0:
           df.loc[index,'New_Value']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['New_Value']=df.New_Value.apply(lambda x: str(x) + '0' if len(str(x))==1 else x)
```

If you want the result to be integer, do this instead:

```
df['New_Value']=df.New_Value.apply(lambda x: int(str(x) + '0') if len(str(x))==1 else x)
```

Comment: I am sorry did not see your solution before. I will remove my solution from this forum. Also, I have made an edit in your solution :)

Comment: No worries, no need to remove yours your edit was useful, i removed my downvote. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('Hellow world')

    for index in df.index:
        if len(list(df.loc[index,'New_Value'])) == 1.0:
           df['New_Value']= data['New_Value].apply(lambda x: int(str(x) + '0'))
           
         elif len(list(df.loc[index,'New_Value']))== 2.0:
           df.loc[index,'New_Value']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
This should solve your purpose:

```
df['New_Value'] = df.New_Value.apply(lambda x: int(str(x) + '0') if len(str(x)) == 1 else x)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   New_Value
0         51
1         10
2         20
3         45
4         20
5         24
```